# Spring Boot Logging level has no effect when application.properties is loaded externally

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I'm running a spring boot app with tomcat.

When application.properties is loaded through classpath, my logging levels are correctly set.

When application.properties is loaded externally with the following java config :

```
@PropertySource(value="file:/some/path/application.properties")
```

"something" override logging.level.* statements, and it seems that a default value is set to INFO level.

What could be wrong ?

Comment: The fact that you are loading the file yourself. This bypasses the specific Spring Boot loading of the `application.properties`. Don't load it with `@PropertySource`. specify the `spring.config.location` instead of loading it yourself.

Comment: I'm using a profile, that's why... I'm trying that way

Comment: my others properties are loaded successfully, that's disapointing

Comment: Just use `application-[profile].yml` files to separate for profiles (that is supported out-of-the-box).

Comment: yes, if the file is within the classpath. in this case my config works out-of-the-box as your said. but i'm loading my file as an external ressource

Comment: No it isn't... If you specify the `spring.config.location` (as stated in my earlier comment and as documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)) if you put your external directory in there it still applies. The classpath and current directory (as documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)) are the default but can be changed/updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of working with `@PropertySource` and expecting the custom Spring Boot loading rules to still work let Spring Boot handle it.

Spring Boot already has support of [loading profile specific property files](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config). By [default](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) it checks the classpath and current directory. However this can be easily extended/changed by specifying a `spring.config.location` property. Just put your custom directory in there.

```
java -jar your-app.jar --spring.config.location=file:/some/path/
```

**Note:** Setting it as an environment or JNDI would also work.

Now this directory will also be checked for property/yml files according to the same loading rules (i.e. `application.properties` and `application-{profile}.properties` and YAML files of course).

Comment: very clear, thanks. i now have a similar behavior accross envs.